# jquery autocomplete with utf8 hebrew letters

Tags: php, utf-8, jquery-autocomplete

I have set up jquery's autocomlete like so:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
     $( "input#Filter" ).autocomplete({
            source: ["בזן", "גאבה", "אוהד", "יוסי", "שחקן"], 
            minLength: 2,
        });
});
</script>
```

and it works!

but I need to get the data from a another php file so I used this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
     $( "input#Filter" ).autocomplete({
            source: "autocomplete.php?file=<?echo $newest?>", 
            minLength: 2,
        });
});
</script>
```

and lets say autocomplete.php is as simple as

```
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
echo json_encode('["אא", "בבבאאא", "גגגאאא"]');
// tried also echo '["אא", "בבבאאא", "גגגאאא"]';
```

no use. looked for many solutions in various forums. 
either it is displayed as jibrish, either the autocompletes displays the entire array no matter what I put in the text box.

look like it's a coding problem..

both of my files are saved as 'ANSI AS UTF-8'.

thanks..

Answer (score 0):

try this autocomplete.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo json_encode('["אא", "בבבאאא", "גגגאאא"]');?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: didn't worked . responsed me this:
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf8">
    </head>
    <body>
        "[\"\u05d0\u05d0\", \"\u05d1\u05d1\u05d1\u05d0\u05d0\u05d0\", \"\u05d2\u05d2\u05d2\u05d0\u05d0\u05d0\"]"    </body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

> First of all I don't have much experience with this autocomplete plugin - these are just some ideas off the top of my head...

I think the problem here is that your PHP file is returning a JSON object where in in actual fact the autcomplete plugin requires a JavaScript array.  I'm assuming this because of the `source` parameter that you passed to the plugin... Its just a normal array...

What you might want to try is something like this -

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
echo '["אא", "בבבאאא", "גגגאאא"]';
exit();
```

---

If that is not the problem and the autcomplete plugin indeed wants to get a JSON response then you can try wrapping your data in a normal PHP array before encoding to JSON -

```
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
$names = array(
  'ליאור',
  'עידו',
  'בן'
);
echo json_encode($names);
exit();
```

Remember to `exit()` after you echo out your JSON data to prevent any other output messing up the JSON format.

Comment: thanks lix, but it didn't work. they both worked in passing the values to the autocomplete, but the autocomplete didnt manage to recognize which to display and which not to display (as it did succeeded when I pass the values as is in the first example I gave.)

Comment: How do you mean what not to display?  The reason you are sending it through your PHP file is so that you can **return only the correct values**... The plugin will display all the results that you return from your AJAX call...

Comment: yeah, just noticed it now when it also displayed all the values in english also... but how am I supposed to send the text value each time?   ---  tried -> source: "autocomplete.php?file=<?echo $newest?>&filter="+ $( "input#Filter" ).text(), and no luck...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I managed to solve it. See my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393727/jquery-autocomplete-not-returning-results-with-e/11737498#11737498) for the details.
In short: change
    source: "autocomplete.php?file=", 
to
    source: "autocomplete.php?file=**encodeURI**()",