# jquery autocomplete not returning results with é

Tags: jquery, utf-8, character-encoding, jquery-autocomplete

I'm having a hard time with a JQquery Autocomplete script. It works fine until I perform a search with a non-UTF8-character in the search query.

For instance: search query "test" succesfully returns results like "test", "test é" etc
but when I add the é to the search query it doesn't give any results any more: (query "test é" returns no results).

When I call the php script that performs the query and returns the the results as an json-array it does show me the correct output: "**[{"id":"1230","value":"Test \u00e9"}]**", it just on the HTML-page that te drop-down with the results is not given anymore.

any advice on this is hugely appreciated.

Walter

Comment: Is there a message in the browser's error console?

Comment: @walter81 `header("Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8");` have you set html content type meta tag as a utf8 ? and php header content type as utf8?,if not try both also you describe the problem a little better do you mean that the list does not show? also have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127124/utf-8-problem-in-using-jquery-autocomplete-tags hope this helps :)

Comment: I've added both headers, without result. And yes I mean that the list does not show. It shows all results when I type "test" but stops when I add the é to the search string ("test é" does not show the list at all). I already checked that link but that seems to be another issue.

Answer (score 0):

I -finally- found it. And, as usual, it's pretty simple:

In the javascript part where I cal the JSON-script I replaced "q: **escape**(request.term)" by "q: **encodeURI**(request.term)". That solved my issue!

```
$("#field")
.autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.getJSON("./ajax/json_search.php", {
            object_type: "artists",
            q: encodeURI(request.term)
            }, response);
        }
})
```